# issue Sending multiple Invitaions using Devise Invitable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise-invitable

this is my controller where I am picking all emails but it is sending mail to last email in emails[] array.

```
def invite_user
    permitted_params = params.permit(emails: [])
    emails = permitted_params[:emails]
  
    # Collect invitations in an array
    invitations = emails.map { |email| { email: email } }
  
    # Send all invitations outside the loop using deliver_later
    invitations.each do |invitation|
      User.invite!(invitation, current_user) 
    end
    
    redirect_to users_path
  end
```

Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "emails"=>["abc@example.com", "hr@google.com"], "commit"=>"Send an invitation"}
getting parameters but invite is sending only to last recipient.